# Cannot change storage transfer service account permissions from terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I am trying to launch a google **storage transfer service** using **url list** from a **cloudfunction**.

For that I need the storage transfer service account to have the following permissions (following the google documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/configure-access#url-list)).
For that, my IAC is the following:

**main.tf**

```hlc
provider "google" {
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

locals {
  storage_transfer_service_account = "project-${var.project}@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_project_service" "storage_transfer_api" {
  project            = var.project
  service            = "storagetransfer.googleapis.com"
  disable_on_destroy = true
}

# For the storage transfer service account
resource "google_project_iam_member" "legacy_bucket_writer" {
  project = var.project
  role    = "roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${local.storage_transfer_service_account}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "object_viewer" {
  project = var.project
  role    = "roles/storage.objectViewer"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${local.storage_transfer_service_account}"
}
```

But when I run my **terraform plan** I get the following error:

```sh
tf.plan : var.project is a string, known only after apply
tf.plan : Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
```

I understand the **project** variable is not set yet during plan, but how can I grant the necessary permission to the service account ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of comments about terraform code only:

1. There is a special terraform data resource - [google_storage_transfer_project_service_account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/storage_transfer_project_service_account) - it might be useful to utilize it. It might look something like (`var.project` means the project ID):

   ```
   data "google_storage_transfer_project_service_account" "st_service_account" {
     project = var.project
   }
   ```
2. Terraform tries to run a lot API commands asynchronously. At the same time some resources may be dependent on others. Sometimes it is possible to infer those dependencies and sometimes there is not enough information in terraform source files. In the alter case a `depends_on` [meta-argument can be used](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/depends_on). There is a piece of code (in your terraform) used to enable a Storage Transfer API. It takes time. From the best of my understanding, the storage transfer service account is created during that API enabling. And until the service account is created, it is not possible to get its details and assign additional IAM roles for it.

Comment: I ran it, it seems to work, but I run into the following error in my terraform plan: Error: Error when reading or editing Google Cloud Storage Transfer service account not found: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden. You would't know role the service account running the terraform needs by any chance ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/access-control says the permission is "storagetransfer.projects.getServiceAccount"  In terms of roles - maybe something from here: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/access-control#predefined-roles-matrix